# Input.GetAxis() always returns 0

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality, oculus

Here is a screenshot of the Input Manager for my project:

[image]

The 9th and 10th axis refer to `Axis1D.PrimaryIndexTrigger (Squeeze)` and `Axis1D.SecondaryIndexTrigger (Squeeze)` respectively, as documented on [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OculusControllers.html).

However, `Input.GetAxis(trigger)` always returns `0`, even when

1. the trigger name is correct, and
2. I am squeezing the corresponding trigger really hard.

While running the debugger, I used my **right** Oculus controller to interact with objects in my scene. Here is the debug window:

[image]

Even though I was squeezing the corresponding trigger on my right Oculus controller, `Input.GetAxis(trigger)` still returned `0`, thus causing my method to return early.

Here are the fields and properties of my `Hand` class, in which I am invoking the `Input.GetAxis(trigger)` method:

```
public enum XRHandControllerNode
{
    Left,
    Right
}

private XRNode trackedXRNode =>
    this.TrackedXRNode == XRHandControllerNode.Left ? XRNode.LeftHand : XRNode.RightHand;

private const float MinimumSqueeze = 0.8f;
private string trigger =>
                   this.TrackedXRNode == XRHandControllerNode.Left ?
                   "LeftIndexTrigger" :
                   "RightIndexTrigger";

public XRHandControllerNode TrackedXRNode;
```

Why does `Input.GetAxis` always return 0, and what changes should I make to ensure that any squeeze of the trigger will be correctly detected?

Answer (score 1):

It was a timing issue. `Input.GetAxis(trigger)` returned values that are negligibly close to 1 in subsequent invocations of `Update()` as I continued squeezing the corresponding trigger on my Oculus controller.